# Is there a way to get Feed The Beast offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My main gaming PC doesn't connect to the internet so I use laptops to do any downloading from the internet.

My old one hasn't been powerful enough to play minecraft at the lowest graphic settings (everything set to low) for a long time now (the new launch has been great cause it's not all that intensive) and my new laptop has got a crappy mousepad where the left and right clicks can also move the mouse (ie, I can go to right click on a link only for the mouse to have moved and I right click the background) however I can tolerate it for running Minecraft Updates since the play button is so big

I update my main PC's minecraft by copying the entirety of the .minecraft folder over and since i've already logged on and downloaded the versions for my profiles I can play offline

When I first got the Feed the Beast Launcher it required me to login but I couldn't see any option to play offline, I want to properly check out Feed the Beast (especially when it becomes compatible with 1.8 for the new biomes) so I want to play it offline on my main PC, So is there a way to get Feed The Beast offline?

Comment: I *think* it is the identical process as the normal minecraft launcher. It'll download the game to whatever folder you specify in its settings, then copy over that folder + the launcher and you should be good to go. Can't check right now though. It *might* save some settings file in a place I don't know about.

Comment: @Arperum Sadly it isn't this easy. Many people online have confirmed the lack of an offline mode in the launcher.

Comment: https://www.hackphoenix.com/feed-the-beast/ works. Legit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this reddit page](http://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/29cd2t/running_ftb_offline/), it isn't possible with the current versions Feed The Beast launcher. Instead, it was suggested that you export the modpack to the MultiMC launcher and launch it offline through that.

## Exporting modpacks to MultiMC

---

In order to play Feed The Beast modpacks with MultiMC, you will need to download them using the offical Feed The Beast launcher first, and then move it to MultiMC. This is what you need to do accomplish this:

[image]

1. Download the [Feed The Beast launcher](http://feed-the-beast.com/launcher), and download the modpack of your desire.
2. After it has downloaded (and you are at the Minecraft main-menu), exit it.
3. Download the MultiMC launcher from [their homepage](http://multimc.org/), extract it, and run it.
4. Click the `Accounts` button in the top right of the main window, and choose `Account Manager`. Proceed to enter your Minecraft login details.

[image]

5. Click the `Add a new instance` button in the top left of the main window. Proceed to name it, and choose the Minecraft version of the original modpack.
6. Navigate to the folder you installed the FTB launcher to, and enter the folder of the modpack you want to export. Copy all the files and folders to your instance folder. This can be located at `<where you extracted MultiMC>/Instances/<your instance name>`

[image]

7. The last thing you need to do is right-click on your modpack instance and click `Edit Mods`. From here click the `Install forge` button on the right-hand side of the window. Proceed to install the latest version of forge for your Minecraft version.

[image]

8. Now, with the instance selected in the main screen, you will be able to click the `Play offline` button in the right sidebar (you may need to be online the first time you try to do this).

And there we go. You can now play Feed The Beast modpacks in offline mode!

I hope this helps.