# Where are my Feed The Beast files stored?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am using FTB's new app launcher, which means many of the previous questions on FTB's modpack file locations don't seem to apply anymore.

The FTB app launcher seems to use the Overwolf app, so I tried looking through the Overwolf folder in Program Files (x86) with no results.

I also tried looking through the %appdata% folder but only found save files for another Overwolf app. There seems to be nothing in my .minecraft folder either.

It appears FTB doesn't save modpacks in folders with clear names as curseforge does.

**So, where are my FTB modpack files located?**

Comment: This is a sore spot with me, too. I have not played this game, but it's nice when a game puts user config in a common location. Have you looked in the Windows registry under HKCU>Software, or maybe in C:\ProgramData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed The Beast doesn't store the more important files in the AppData/Roaming folder.

It instead places the files in the AppData/Local folder.

**The specific folder is AppData/Local/.ftba** where it shows you the instances that you have downloaded

(The instances can be used in [MultiMC to run modpacks offline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185196/is-there-a-way-to-get-feed-the-beast-offline/185199#185199) since both curseforge and feed the beast require an online connection to start).

**This is most likely the generic folder location** and can be changed as JonathanDavidArndt's answer states.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, they are on your desktop:
https://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/file-locations.2327/

> Make a folder named FTB in the AppData\Roaming\ftblauncher folder.
> Install the launcher there, make a shortcut and move it to your desktop.

This article says it depends on your settings, and you can modify the path from "Options":
https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/1w6nz6/where_are_the_ftb_files_stored/

> Depends on your settings. Go to Options and you can view or edit the path there.

And according to the wiki, files are stored to the location that you installed FTB from (using the launcher) in the first place:
https://ftbwiki.org/Tutorial:Installing_Feed_The_Beast_on_PC

> When it has finished downloading, you can move the .exe anywhere you wish, your desktop, My Documents, Downloads. I took a little bit of time and made a .feedthebeast folder in my roaming next to .minecraft. By default, all of the Modpacks will install to the folder you specify to have it download to.